# why i'm getting the creationTime -1 ,number of Hits -1, and lastAccessedTime is also -1 why shile upgrading the hazelcast from 3.x.x to 5.x.x

Tags: java, migration, hazelcast

Please some one provide some changes to this code so that i will not get -1 in creationTime -1 ,number of Hits -1, and lastAccessedTime is also -1
// like i'm trying to solve this problem from the last 4 days please help me

````
```
package com.evolvedintelligence.engine.sigfirewall.preferences;
import com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient;
import com.hazelcast.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.hazelcast.config.Config;
import com.hazelcast.config.InMemoryFormat;
import com.hazelcast.config.MapConfig;
import com.hazelcast.core.EntryView;
import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.map.IMap;
import com.hazelcast.map.LocalMapStats;

import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class myClass {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(myClass.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Start the Hazelcast Server
        Config configs = new Config();

        HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(configs);

        // Start the Hazelcast Client
        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        config.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("127.0.0.1:5701");

        // Connect to the Hazelcast server
        HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
        IMap<String, String> map = client.getMap("mymap");

        //putting an entry with the key "key1"
        map.put("key1", "value1");
        // Get the entry view of the key "key1"

        EntryView<String, String> entryView = map.getEntryView("key1");


        LOGGER.info("hits: "+ entryView.getHits()+" Key: " + entryView.getKey() + " Value: " + entryView.getValue() + " Creation Time: " + entryView.getCreationTime() + " Cost: " + entryView.getCost() + ", Version: " + entryView.getVersion());
//        LocalMapStats entryView = map.getLocalMapStats();
//        LOGGER.info("KEY: --    "+entryView.getCreationTime()+"      SIZE----   "+entryView.getHeapCost()+"    HITS    "+ entryView.getHits());

    }
}








```
````

**OUTPUT is given below**
hits: -1 Key: key1 Value: value1 Creation Time: -1 Cost: 70, Version: 0

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [documentation page](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/latest/migrate/upgrading-from-imdg-3) dedicated to upgrading from Hazelcast 3.x to 4/5.x.
From this page:

> Changes in Client Connection Retry Mechanism
> The `connection-attempt-period` and `connection-attempt-limit` configuration have been removed. Instead, the elements of `connection-retry` are now used. See [Configuring Client Connection Retry](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/latest/clients/java#configuring-client-connection-retry) for the usage of those new elements.